# Maintaining non-resident status while working remotely in Canada

Tags: canada, non-residents

I am a Canadian expat who is a permanent resident of Bermuda. At this point I have been here over seven years and have taken the steps necessary to sever ties with Canada from a CRA perspective. My company is going to be in working from home mode until well into next year. My thought is that it would be great to work remotely from Canada to be with family.

I do not, however, want to jeopardize my non-resident status. Questions here, various internet searches, and Canada's immigration web site all seem to have information about non-Canadians getting resident status not the other way around.

Do I need to be worried about my non-resident status if I stay in Canada for four to six months?

Comment: Are you sure that CRA considers that you have severed your residential ties to Canada?  
https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/international-non-residents/information-been-moved/determining-your-residency-status.html

Comment: I think it might help potential answers if you tell us where you are resident now and your immigration status there.

Comment: Edited in info as requested.